# How to move a file in a shared google drive to trash using a service account

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, shared-drive

I use a service account that is content-manager. I have no problem uploading files to the shared drive using the drive-api from python. Using

```py
service.files().list(q="name='file_name'", fields="files(id)").execute()
```

I obtain the file_id from my code. This file_id is the right one based on the link to the file.

When I perform the following statement:

```py
response = service.files().update(fileId=file_id, body={'trashed': True}).execute()
```

I get a

> 404: file not found.

How to resolve this ? With my personal account (also as content-manager) I have no problems trashing the file.

Comment: Which Drive API version are you using?

Comment: @JoseVasquez I am using Drive api v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Requirements

***If you clearly understand how to impersonate an account you can skip to the `Solution` step.***

- First of all you will need a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount)
- Delegate [domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)
- Make sure that you are correctly [calling the API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)

### Solution

By default [Python Google Drive API client V3](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/index.html) doesn't include shared drive files, that's why you have to explicitly pass a parameter `supportsAllDrives` and set it to True and before that you should list your files in order to know the **fileId** parameter by using `includeItemsFromAllDrives` and `supportsAllDrives`. Here's an example to list all the files in all your drives and how to trash a file in a Shared Drive using a service account:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = './service_account_key.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Impersonate user@example.com account in my example.com domain
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@example.com')

# Use the delegated credentials to impersonate the user
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)

# List all the files in your Drives (Shared Drives included)
results = service.files().list(fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, trashed)", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1}) - Trashed? {2}'.format(item['name'], item['id'], item['trashed']))

# Use the filedId in order to trash your shared file
response = service.files().update(fileId=fileId, body={'trashed': True}, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
print(response)
```

Otherwise if you already know the **fileId** just use the `update` part.

### Reference

[Python Google Drive API client V3 > Update a file](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#update)

[Google Identity Platform > Impersonate a user by using a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)